# Netgear A6210 not installed on ubuntu 17.10

Tags: networking, wireless, 17.10, netgear

I am trying to install driver for Netgear a6210.

I executed:

```
git clone https://github.com/genodeftest/Netgear-A6210.git
make
```

And I got this error message:

```
In function ‘memcpy’,
    inlined from ‘rt_ioctl_iwaplist’ at /media/angelo/Elements1/netgear_linux/Netgear-A6210/os/linux/../../os/linux/sta_ioctl.c:549:2:
./include/linux/string.h:305:4: error: call to ‘__read_overflow2’ declared with attribute error: detected read beyond size of object passed as 2nd parameter
    __read_overflow2();
```

Any ideas?

Comment: What's your kernel version (see the output of `uname -a`) and driver revision (see the output of `git log -n 1 --oneline` inside the driver source code directory)? Which instructions are you following and to what end? Please [edit] your post to add information instead of posting a comment.

Answer (score 1):

Please try:

```
wget https://github.com/genodeftest/Netgear-A6210/archive/port-to-4.13.zip
unzip port-to-4.13.zip
cd Netgear-A6210-port-to-4.13
make
sudo make install
```

Reboot and tell us if the wireless is working; we will probably have one more step.